# Move content of wp_post meta data into table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins

The data submitted using forms,are saved into wp_post ,what I need is whenever I receive data through this form,to move these data into a table (moving not copy:to avoid redundancy) in order to be able to use the content in this tsble easily.

**How I know how the attributes that are saved,since the form is saved as post meta box,using Ninja form.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roaa, the ninja forms data is already stored in a table, the table wp_postmeta,  keyed by post_id. The post_id is the form id.  The form id is from the wp_post table which has an entry for each submission.

See the form submissions under the submissions menu: .../wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=nf_sub  This data can be accessed for other means using

1. the wpdb class https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
2. or the wp function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/ using post_ty[e nf_sub,  or
3. mysql queries if querying outside of wordpress

Comment: Sorry if I need to ask more questions.Yes I know that it's stored in a table,but the situation is that ,that table I want to create having the entries of the form as columns,in addition to other columns,and in other way I have a form:name,email,phone,question. I want to redirect the entries received into a subsite,in order to answer the question and save everything on a single table.Hopefully I get help from you.Much appreciated

Comment: any assist dear @anmari ?

Comment: Roaa, you need to at least try yourself.  Basically you need to find where the data is stored (the tables I mentioned above), then you need to work out how to select the data from the tables in the way that you want, either using get_posts mentioned above or possible using sql queries via the wpdb class (also mentioned above). Then once you are able to select the data and restructure it the way you want it, then you write an update/insert sql statement to add the data into your desired table.   
There is heaps of info on  the web on how to do all this.